# Why does cooking oil lower the vapor pressure of water?

Tags: boiling-point, vapor-pressure

I added different amounts of oil to different containers with 50mL of water and weighted the containers. Then I heated the containers for 15 minutes in a water bath and weighted again. I noticed that the mass of each container was less as I added more oil to the mixture.

So how does oil increases the boiling point/decreases the vapor pressure of water?

Comment: I have two questions here. 1) If you added more oil, but the container weighed less after the heating, it seems like more water evaporated from the containers with more oil. Thus it seems like the oil has *increased* the vapor pressure. 2) Was there any particular reason you were doing this?